# Subset rows which have a column inside numeral interval

Tags: r, subset, numeric

I would like to subset all lines which have "chr" column from 1 to 29, in a "cnv1" dataframe.

I tried it:

```
cnvk <- cnv1[cnv1$chr==1:29,]
```

But it do not get all lines which have 1,2,3...29.

Cheers!

Comment: you should use `%in%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
cnvk <- cnv1[cnv1$chr %in% 1:29,]
```

or

```
cnvk <- cnv1[cnv1$chr>=1 & cnv1$chr<=29,]
```

(The latter might be quicker if you're checking against a large range of values)